# Redirect ip to domain on apachi (wordpress by bitnami)

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, bitnami

I just created a wordpress site on aws using bitnami and pointed it to my domain. The problem is the site can be accessible via both the IP and domain. How do I redirect the IP to domain?

Answer (score 0):

Create a default VirtualHost (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html) that responds to any unqualified host name (and the bare IP address) and a second VirtualHost that can only be reached when your desired hostname/domain is used. Redirect (at the http level) the default VirtualHost to your domain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default
    Redirect "/" "http://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    #  enter other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I tried but that doesn't work.